# Scored similarity searches in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Goal**: Implement a SQL query in a Snowflake database that, given an address-like string string (user input), does a fuzzy/approximate search against a single field, returning results with a similarity score, ordered by that score.

I see that Snowflake offers a few tools that seem related to this problem, such as APPROXIMATE_SIMILARITY and MINHASH,  but it's not clear to me *which* of these tools I need or how to put them together. The [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-approximate-similarity.html) is good, but lacking a straightforward example, and seems to focus on the similarity of two tables, rather than comparing an arbitrary string to values in a column.

Given `user_input` and field `locations`.`FullAddress`, I'm looking for something like this pseudo query:

```
SELECT "score", field1, field2 from locations 
WHERE FullAddress LIKE user_input;
```

I know there's more to it than that but just can't quite see how to integrate the functions provided by Snowflake to make it work.

Here is a sample of the locations table - note that the complete address is in a single field, and can be rendered in inconsistent ways.

```
| Somefield | FullAddress                                      | OtherField |
|-----------|--------------------------------------------------|------------|
| foo       | 123 SW Marble Street, Brainerd MA 55555          | yellow     |
| bar       | 98 Main, San Diego CA 99999                      | green      |
| beep      | 123 SW Marble St, Brainerd 55555-2222            | orange     |
| baz       | 456 Somewhere Blvd, Apt 23, Boise ID, 44444-1234 | blue       |
```

A user might search for `123 SW Marble Street, Brainerd MA 55555` (a perfect match). I would hope to return rows 1 and 3, with row 1 getting the highest score. Or user might search for `123 Marble Street` (imperfect) and I would still want to return rows 1 and 3, ranked by the similarity algorithm.

Comment: I would try using this function: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/jarowinkler_similarity.html

Comment: Please share some sample input, and desired results so we can offer you options

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I have added sample data. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three built-in fuzzy matching functions in Snowflake, `JAROWINKLER_SIMILARITY` (mentioned by NickW), `EDITDISTANCE` and `SOUNDEX`. It's a simple matter to extend this library using Java, Python, or JavaScript code in a UDF.

Here is an example of the three built-in functions compared to a given address:

```
set comparison = '123 SW Marble Street, Brainerd MA 55555';
select  *
        ,JAROWINKLER_SIMILARITY($comparison, full_address)
        ,EDITDISTANCE($comparison, full_address)
        ,SOUNDEX($comparison) = SOUNDEX(full_address)
from T1
```

Comment: Oh! It's so much easier than I thought, based on the documentation.  With the addition of an `ORDER BY` and a `LIMIT`, and using just one of the functions (I'll start with Jarowinkler), this gets me exactly what I needed. Thank you! An example like this in the docs would be very much welcome.